# Using PHP convert hex code 0xbb to html entity &raquo;

Tags: php, regex, hex, preg-match

As the title says, I'm trying to use PHP to convert the character `»` into it's html entity. This is not our final solution, but before some other major changes are finished, we need this as a quick fix.

I'm trying to test out with the following code, but its not working as I'd wanted.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['test'])){
    $converted = preg_replace('/\xbb/', '&raquo;', $_POST['test']);
    echo '<div>Original: '.$_POST['test'].'</div>';
    echo '<div>Converted: '. $converted.'</div>';
}
?>
```

The converted seems to be correct but we are getting an extra character before the `&raquo;` which shows in Firefox's view source as just a ? in a square, but I'm not sure what it actually is or why it is there.

Please can someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`»` is `c2 bb` in UTF-8 but `bb` in ISO-8859-1.

When outputting this on a page that is not UTF-8 encoded, you'll see something like this:

```
Â» or 
�»
```

The chances are, the character is being posted through as UTF-8. That means the second byte is being replaced, but the first remains, so you end up with `c2` followed by `&raquo;`

Try

```
$converted = preg_replace('/\xbb/u', '&raquo;', $var);
```

or

```
$converted = preg_replace('/\xc2\xbb/', '&raquo;', $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `u` modifier:

```
$converted = preg_replace('/\xbb/u', '&raquo;', $_POST['test']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`»` character in unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bb/index.htm) is represented as hexadecimal `00bb`.  Your regex is matching the second byte only, so you still have a null byte remaining.  This would work:

```
$converted = preg_replace('/\x00\xbb/', '&raquo;', $_POST['test']);
```

Or you can use another modifier that is specifically intended to match a unicode character, but I don't know PHP well enough to say confidently what would work.

Comment: It's Unicode code point `00 bb` which is UTF-8 encoded as `c2 bb`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dan1111, it doesn't work in my case but I don't know enough about it to know why.

Comment: @LukeCousins, Craig Mason was correct about the file being encoded in UTF-8.  That is why his answer worked and mine didn't.  I'm glad you found a solution.